# 2D Array with Number Averages

Tags: java

Here is the original question:

Write a program that declares a 2-dimensional array of doubles called scores with three rows and three columns. Use a nested while loop to get the nine (3 x 3) doubles from the user at the command line. Finally, use a nested for loop to compute the average of the doubles in each row and output these three averages to the command line.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Scorer {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    double [][] scores = new double[3][3];
    double value = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (count < 3) {

        while (count < 9) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            value = scnr.nextDouble();
            count++;
        }
    }

    int average = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {

        for (j = 0; j < scores[i].length; j++) {
            average += value;
            value = value / scores[i][j];
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }

}

}
```

I edited the code now to show my new nested for loops at the bottom. These are supposed to compute the average of the entered numbers, however, I am not sure why it does not work?

Comment: Trace through your program on paper, it should start to make more sense to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two variables, one for the row, and one for the column:

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

double [][] scores = new double[3][3];
double value = 0;

int i=0;
int j;

while (i < 3) {
    j=0;
    while (j < 3) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        value = scnr.nextDouble();
        scores[i][j]=value;
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: After three iterations, it just stops like this:

Comment: Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 8
Enter a number: 26
4

Comment: The nested for loop is going to be used to compute the average, however, I cannot figure out why it just outputs a bunch of zeros?

Comment: Also, I couldnt for the life of me figure out how to format the code in the comment section

Comment: `int average = 0; for (i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) { for (j = 0; j < scores.length; j++) { average += value; average = average / 3; System.out.println(average); } }`

Answer (score 0):

This logic is weird and never can be met

```
 while (count < 3) {

        while (count < 9) {
```

at the moment that count is bigger than 3  you will never see again the while at `count<9`

you should think again and reorder the  conditional check of that value..

```
 while (count < 9) {

        while (count < 3) {
```

could make more sense...

Comment: Why 2 while loops?

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite this segment:

```
int count = 0;
while (count < 3) {

    while (count < 9) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        value = scnr.nextDouble();
        count++;
    }
}
```

...to

```
double row_sum, value;
double[] row_means;
int row_count = 0, col_count;

while (row_count < 3) {
    row_sum = 0.0;
    col_count = 0;

    while (col_count < 3) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        // TODO: consider adding some input validation
        value = scnr.nextDouble();
        row_sum +=  value;
        scores[row_count][col_count++] = value;
    }

    row_means[row_count++] = row_sum / 3.0;
}
```

... which simultaneously populates your matrix and computes the mean.

Comment: I need to use the nested for loops to compute the average of the mean and the nested while loops to get the user input and populate the array

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can have one loop;

```
while (count < 9) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    value = scnr.nextDouble();
    scores[count/3][count%3]=value;
    count++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about it in terms of **English** or pseudo code first, it will be surprisingly easier.

```
//In English, to get average from 1 row:
/*
1) sum every elements in the row
2) divide sum by number of elements
*/
```

In codes:

```
int y = 0;
while(y < col){               //loop through all columns
    sum += scores[0][y];
    y++;
}
avg = sum / col;
```

If you can get the average of just one row, congratulations, your work is more than half done. Simply repeat the above process for all other rows with another loop. (This explains why you need 2 loops. One for the columns, the other for the rows).

```
//In English, to get average from all rows:
/*
1) sum every elements in the row
2) divide sum by number of elements
3) repeat the above till all rows are done
*/
```

In codes:

```
int x = 0;
while(x < row){               //loop through all rows
    int y = 0;
    while(y < col){           //loop through all columns
        sum += scores[x][y];
        y++;
    }
    avg[x] = sum / col;       //avg needs to be array now, since you need to store 3 values
    x++;
}
```

---

**To get values from `row` and `col`:**

```
int row = scores.length;
int col = scores[0].length;
```

Comment: @java2019 Take a look at my solution.